# Does anyone know of a modern city council with more than two dozen members?

Tags: local-government

Does anyone know of a modern city council with more than two dozen members?

> As part of his reforms Emperor Diocletian made Ovilava the capital city of the province of Noricum Ripensis. It was governed by two duumviri who served as municipal judges, two aediles, who advocated compliance with the laws and market rights, a quaestor, who managed the city treasury, and a 100-member city council.

Ovilava is now [Wels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wels), the eighth largest city in Austria.

Comment: In what country? In the UK, local councils (city or otherwise) routinely have far more than 24 members. E.g. Birmingham (101), Liverpool (90), Manchester (96), and so on. Or are you talking the cabinets which run those cities?

Comment: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) "there is no actual problem to be solved". Expect answers that "are more than just mindless social fun". VTC

Comment: As of March 2022, New York City had the largest city council of the top 100 cities by population, consisting of 51 seats. https://ballotpedia.org/List_of_current_city_council_officials_of_the_top_100_cities_in_the_United_States Chicago has 50 seats. Nashville TN has 36. St. Louis has 28.

Comment: @RickSmith There are many well received "Are there any..." type questions on politics. Here's [one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/8320/are-there-any-political-parties-in-saudi-arabia) example. What makes this question different from that one?

Comment: @code11 - The existence of political parties in Saudi Arabia could have political consequences and there is a "political" question asked about establishment of such parties. The size of city councils, in and of itself, has none that I can see. One might ask about the size of city councils and effectiveness of representation, but this question doesn't ask about that. In other words, there is no "political" question to be answered.

Comment: @RickSmith The machinery of elections and governments is almost by definition part of "politics". Not the world's most profound one, but it is clearly on point. Politics isn't limited to what does or does not advance a faction's interests.

Comment: @ohwilleke - *Politics isn't limited ...*, but Politics SE identifies certain criteria: [policy, processes and conflicting egos](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I found this question lacking by those measures, as I understand them. Consider for example, *Why have a large city council?* would be a policy question with a possible substantive, objective answer.

Comment: @RickSmith I would see this as "Processes are central to how legislation is made. Questions seeking to understand the rules and processes by which policy is made in various legislatures or ruling bodies (inside and outside of the United States!) are wholly on topic"

Comment: So what? What would be the political point of this question? I don't think it can say anything about the optimal size of a city council since there are a lot of outliers created for historical reasons and the question will focus on them.

Comment: The point of the question is my curiosity about something I had not previously experienced.  This may not be a "policy question" but obviously it has a "substantive, objective answer."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. At least in the U.K. and the U.S. there are quite a few.

In continental Europe (explored by @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil in another answer), local government councils tend to be smaller than the largest ones in the U.K. (although some have more than 100), but bigger than the typical ones in the United States and are often organized on a partisan basis.

[united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)

> In the UK, local councils (city or otherwise) routinely have far more
> than 24 members. E.g. Birmingham (101), Liverpool (90), Manchester
> (96), and so on.

Per @SteveMeinekoff in the comments.

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

In the U.S., these include. [for example](https://ballotpedia.org/List_of_current_city_council_officials_of_the_top_100_cities_in_the_United_States), "as of March 2022, New York City had the largest city council of the top 100 cities by population, consisting of 51 seats." Chicago has 50 seats. Nashville TN has 36. St. Louis, MO has 28. In both New York City and Nashville, at least, city and county government functions are consolidated in a single governmental entity.

Obviously, this isn't a comprehensive list of all such large city councils. [As of 2018](https://worldpopulationreview.com/us-city-rankings/how-many-cities-are-in-the-us), there were 19,495 municipalities in the United States, although 14,768 had less than 5,000 people and were highly unlikely to have a large council which would be more likely to be found in the 310 U.S. cities with more than 100,000 people.

In most, but not all U.S. cities, city council people are elected on a non-partisan basis, or on the basis of informal local political parties not aligned with national parties.

Also, many town governments in New England still make some decisions at town meetings at which all persons eligible to vote in the entire town are entitled to attend, a number well in excess of 24 in almost every case, even though day to day business is handled mostly by elected officials.

The U.S. also tends to have counties, sometimes townships, school boards, and other special districts in addition to municipal governments as local governments and one reason that U.S. municipal government councils tend to be relatively small is because local government is typically spread across more kinds of local governments with elected officials than is common in the U.K. or continental Europe.

Comment: In case anyone comes away from the last paragraph with the misapprehension that local government in the UK is either flat or simple to understand, most of the UK population live in an area with at least 2 elected tiers (from country [Wales, Scotland, N.Irelane, not England], region, county, district or parish) and a sizeable proportion have 3. The are also (unelected) combined authorities and smattering of directly elected officials (primarily mayors and police & crime commissioners). All of these tend to be large, at least vs the US. 3 layer government is fairly common across Europe as well.

Comment: @origimbo Not saying that it is entirely flat, but before I moved to Denver (which has a consolidated government) there were at least nine or ten levels of sub-national government where I lived in Western Colorado. The situation was similar in the couple of places I lived in Ohio.

Comment: @ohwilleke There are two types of New England town meeting: open and closed. The ones you describe are open, where the whole town can show up and vote, but closed town meetings still tend to be very large. For example, the Town of Brookline, Massachusetts elects 255 "town meeting members," which makes the town meeting larger than the state legislature. However, the day-to-day operation of the town is managed by the 5-person Select Board.

Comment: The largest town meeting is probably in Andover, Massachusetts, where (at least in theory) all 25,000 citizen residents over the age of 18 could decide to participate.

Answer (score 6):

Two dozen councilors seems to me to be on the small side for a large city.

[austria](/questions/tagged/austria)

Each [municipality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipality_(Austria)) has a legislative council (*Geminderat*) elected by the municipality's voters, and an executive council (*Gemeindevorstand*) with fewer members. The largest council is that of the largest town, [Vienna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipal_Council_and_Landtag_of_Vienna) (1.95M inhabitants), with 100 members. [Wels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wels) today, with 80k inhabitants, has a 36-member [council](https://www.wels.gv.at/politik/gemeinderat/).

[france](/questions/tagged/france)

The size of a [municipal council](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Municipal_council_(France)#Composition) increases with the number of inhabitants. It ranges from 7 (<100 inhab.) to 163 (Paris, ~2.2M). More than two dozen members is reached at 3500 inhabitants.

The municipal council has both a legislative role (within the explicitly delimited powers granted to municipalities in France) and an executive role. The executive role is exercised by a small number of councilors elected by the plenary council: the [mayor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayor_(France)) and deputy mayors. The number of deputy mayors can vary, but they can consist in no more than 30% of the council.

Going by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wels#Roman_Era), Ovilava had about 18,000 inhabitants a century before Diocletian. At that size, in France, it would have 33 municipal councilors.

[belgium](/questions/tagged/belgium)

The size of a [communal council](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conseil_communal_(Belgique)) ranges from 7 (<100 inhabitants) to 55 (≥300k). More than two dozen members is reached at 15000 inhabitants. 18,000 inhabitants would have 25 councilors.

[switzerland](/questions/tagged/switzerland)

The organization of municipal government depends on the canton, and can vary even for similar-sized municipalities in the same canton. As an example, [Zurich](https://www.zuerich.com/en/visit/about-zurich/the-political-system) (Switzerland's largest municipality, about 420k) has a legislative council with 125 members and an executive council with 9 members. Geneva (200k) has a [legislative council](https://www.geneve.ch/en/authorities-government/city-council) with 80 members and an [executive council](https://www.geneve.ch/en/authorities-government/executive-council) with 5 members.

[italy](/questions/tagged/italy)

The size of a city council tends to increase with the number of inhabitants. According to City Mayors they can range from 15 to 80 members. However, [Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Council_of_Rome) (2.6M) and [Milan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Council_of_Milan) (1.2M) each have a 48-member council, while [Naples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mayors_of_Naples) (0.96M) and [Turin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mayors_of_Turin) (0.87M) have a 40-member council.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know of a modern city council with more than two dozen members?

[singapore](/questions/tagged/singapore)

Singapore is a city-state in Southeast Asia. Its legislative body, the [Parliament of Singapore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliament_of_Singapore), has more than two dozen members: according to Wikipedia, it currently has 103 and may have up to 105.